# How to cancel all requests in Alamofire's shared manager

Tags: alamofire

How to cancel all requests in Alamofire's shared manager?

This is my function:

```
class func cancelAllRequests() {
    Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance.session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (dataTasks, uploadTasks, downloadTasks) in
        self.each(dataTasks, function: self.cancel)
        self.each(uploadTasks, function: self.cancel)
        self.each(downloadTasks, function: self.cancel)
    }
}

class func cancel(index: Int, element: AnyObject) {
    if let task = element as? NSURLSessionTask {
        task.cancel()
    }
}

class func each<T>(array: [T], function: (Int, T) -> ()) {
    for (index, t) in enumerate(array) {
        function(index, array[index])
    }
}
```

Can it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `NSURLSession`'s `invalidateAndCancel` method:

```
manager.session.invalidateAndCancel
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it works. In the API document, it says " finishTasksAndInvalidate and invalidateAndCancel do not have any effect on the shared session singleton."

Comment: OK, so create your own manager that instantiates a new session.

Comment: After calling this i am not able to make request again

Comment: how to recreate session after that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is for **Swift 4.0** and **Alamofire Version 4.5**

```
Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.getAllTasks{ $0.forEach{ $0.cancel() } }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Alamofire version 5.0+, SessionManager has been replaced by Session. Just use

```
Session.default.cancelAllRequests()
```

to cancel all currently running requests created by `AF.request()`.